# How to set drawable on background of View? Android

Tags: android, background, android-canvas, drawable, draw

I have next code in my custom view that extends EditText:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

                int count = getLineCount();
                Canvas cvs= new Canvas();
                Drawable dr = this.getBackground();
                Rect r = mRect;
                Paint paint = mPaint;
                mTextPaint.setTextSize(this.getTextSize());
                Paint PaintText = mTextPaint;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);
                    cvs.drawText(Integer.toString(i+1), r.left, baseline + 1, PaintText);
                    cvs.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint); 
                }
                cvs.drawLine(PaintText.measureText(Integer.toString(count)), this.getTop(), PaintText.measureText(Integer.toString(count)), this.getBottom(), paint);
                dr.setBounds(0, 0, this.getRight(), this.getBottom());
                dr.draw(cvs);
                this.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
            }
```

Why is there nothing on backgroind of this view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int count = getLineCount();
    Canvas cvs= new Canvas(bitmap);
    cvs.drawColor(Color.rgb(245, 245, 245));
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(this.getTextSize());
    Paint PaintText = mTextPaint;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);
        cvs.drawText(Integer.toString(i+1), 2, baseline + 1, PaintText);
        cvs.drawLine(2, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint); 
    }

    cvs.drawLine(PaintText.measureText(Integer.toString(count))+3, this.getTop(), PaintText.measureText(Integer.toString(count))+3, this.getBottom(), paint);

    this.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), bitmap));
    this.setPadding((int) (PaintText.measureText(Integer.toString(count))+7),3,3,3); 
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to do something that can be done easier. However, your code doesn't work because:

1. You don't set a `Bitmap` for your `Canvas` object.
2. I think that you want to move content of the `Canvas` to the `Drawable` but in fact your code performs an opposite action. Actually, you draw the `Drawable` on the `Canvas` object. Try this:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas cvs = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // Your drawing stuff without dr.setBounds() and dr.draw()
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(
        new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), bitmap));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but now I have 2 problems: 1. Its black color of this bitmap. 2. android:padding acts on this background ( . I just want to set left padding for text in this view -  http://i.imgur.com/1doN8.png

Comment: Use `Canvas.drawColor()` to change color of `Bitmap`. Can you please describe your goal in detail?

Comment: I doing custom edittext with linenumbering, but the problem is that user's text is superimposed on top draw the text, as you can see on the picture.

Comment: So as far as I understand, padding of the `EditText` changes when new background drawable is set.

Comment: I just want to set padding only for text.

Comment: Have you tried to set it with the `setPadding()` method of your view? Setting a `BitmapDrawable` as a view's background mustn't affect view's padding.

Comment: I think so too. Therefore, I tried to do all this as background.Here, the result of adding  MainEdit.setPadding(20,0,0,0); at onCreate: http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/6361/devicess.png

Comment: I decided it. The problem was in r.left.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a new Canvas object. onDraw creates one for you and sets it in its own bitmap. Just use the name of the canvas specified in the parameters (in this case, canvas).

onDraw is called everytime your view is created or invalidate() is called. And in your onDraw() method, you are creating a NEW canvas object. If you are using this code for anything graphically intense (like a game) then you are leaking memory. Even if you only draw your view once, this is not the best way to do so. Use the canvas provided in the onDraw() parameters.